# How to create primary key by using two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create table with two columns. These columns have to be created with primary key. For example Column 1 name `ID` and column 2 name `Name`. `ID` is auto incremented. When data is inserted into the table, all names has to be different. How can I do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableNameHere
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable
PRIMARY KEY(ID, Name)
```

and to make sure the `Name` is unique:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableNameHere
ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_Name UNIQUE(Name)
```